# Retrieve Android app icon from package name from

Tags: android, rest

Is there any Http (REST) API to retrieve the icon of an Android application from a given package name?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to find this app on google play or you want to get icon of installed app?

Comment: I want to access this through a web app, not from the android device itself

Comment: Ok, As I know, there is no public API to google play. Sorry